# Android: Add a style to the actionbar on one activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, styles, android-actionbar

I want to add a style from styles.xml

```
<style name="BlueActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

to my Actionbar but just on the Activity BlueActivity (which is still blank). How to do that? I'm stuck :'(

**edit:**
Why does adding

```
android:actionBarStyle="@style/BlueActionBar"
```

to BlueActivity in the Manifest not work?

Comment: because you can't set actionbar style in AndroidManifest for activity :) You can set only theme for activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Project.Activity1" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Project.Activity1.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Project.Activity1.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.Activity1"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.Project.Activity1"
/>
```